# Queryable.Intersect not working on object

Tags: c#

I have the following object, `Role`, defined as :

```
public class Role
{
    public String RoleName { get; set; }
    public Guid RoleGuid { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return (this.RoleName == ((Role)obj).RoleName);
    }
}
```

I also have a collection modeled as `RolesCollection`, defined as:

```
public class RolesCollection : IList<Role>, IEqualityComparer<Role>, IEnumerable<Role>
{
    private readonly IList<Role> _list = new List<Role>();
    public Role this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _list[index];
        }

        set
        {
            _list[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _list.Count;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return _list.IsReadOnly;
        }
    }

    public void Add(Role item)
    {
        _list.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(Role item)
    {
        return _list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(Role[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Equals(Role x, Role y)
    {
        return (x.RoleName == y.RoleName);
    }

    public IEnumerator<Role> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Role obj)
    {
        return obj.RoleName.GetHashCode();
    }

    public int IndexOf(Role item)
    {
        Role interalItem = _list.First<Role>(i => i.RoleName == item.RoleName);
        return _list.IndexOf(interalItem);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, Role item)
    {
        _list.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public bool Remove(Role item)
    {
        return _list.Remove(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        _list.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Now comes my Unit `Tests.EqualsTest()`, which is passing and  `RolesIntersectTest()`, which is failing. It should give me 2 but it gives me 0.

```
[TestClass()]
public class RoleTests
{
    public RolesCollection Source { get; set; }
    public RolesCollection Destination { get; set; }
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void SetUp() {
        Source = new RolesCollection();
        Source.Add(new Role() { RoleGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(), RoleName = "Baker" });
        Source.Add(new Role() { RoleGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(), RoleName = "Tailor" });
        Source.Add(new Role() { RoleGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(), RoleName = "Chef" });

        Destination = new RolesCollection();
        Destination.Add(new Role() { RoleGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(), RoleName = "Baker" });
        Destination.Add(new Role() { RoleGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(), RoleName = "Tailor" });
        Destination.Add(new Role() { RoleGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(), RoleName = "Teacher" });
    }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void EqualsTest()
    {
        Role role1 = new Role() {
            RoleGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(),
            RoleName = "Vinay"
        };
        Role role2 = new Role()
        {
            RoleGuid = System.Guid.NewGuid(),
            RoleName = "Vinay"
        };
        Assert.IsTrue(role1.Equals(role2));

    }
    [TestMethod()]
    public void RolesIntersectTest() {
        RolesCollection results = Source.Intersect(Destination) as RolesCollection;
        Assert.IsTrue(results.Count() > 1);
    }
}
```

Please advice.

Comment: Is it results.Count() that should be giving you 2?

Comment: @b729sefc, yes this is what I am expecting, however I get 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement GetHashCode on your Role class.

Lots of equality stuff (especially for hash tables/sets, which Intersect uses behind the scenes) expects both Equals and GetHashCode to be implemented together consistently.